# Div not reappearing using jQuery .show() after hiding with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div hide and then show itself when the page has fully loaded.

The div tag doesn't appear but then it also never loads and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#home-pro-slider').show();
});
</script>

<div class="container nopadding">
<div class="row">
<div id="home-pro-slider" class="slider-pro bsnojs" style="display:none;">



</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My console shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at (index):479

I believe this is caused by me not loading in jQuery before I run this snippet, but I have the reference in my header before this code runs as far as I am aware.

**EDIT**: Apologies, I made an error copying and pasting my code, the missing ')' is indeed there, I still have the issue.

Comment: Check the console for any errors. You're missing `);` on line 5, that might be your problem.

Comment: @NikkiMather thanks for pointing that out but that was just a mistake when I copied the code to stackoverflow, I still have my issue.

Comment: have you tried on load function? instead of document ready

Answer (score 1):

Add a `)` as error message clearly shows.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#home-pro-slider').show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, missing a the `)` of the ready function

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#home-pro-slider').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just read your edit and the problem you face is that jQuery is not initialized properly. You have to define your jQuery-Script-Tag **first** and then follow it up with other scripts like so:

```
<head>
   .
   css and meta info
   .
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

I also want to add that you should always separate your code. CSS belongs into a separate CSS-file and **not** inline. The javascript belongs into a separate file as well and the `text/javascript` or `application/javascript`-tags are deprecated and should be left out.

---

As you can see below: It does work but because the div was empty you could not see anything. If you somehow load your javascript before you initialize the `div` it might not be able to find it but with `$(document).ready()` this can't be the case.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#home-pro-slider').show();
});
```

```css
#home-pro-slider {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container nopadding">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="home-pro-slider" class="slider-pro bsnojs">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Missing close tag

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#home-pro-slider').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#home-pro-slider').show();
});
</script>

<div class="container nopadding">
<div class="row">
<div id="home-pro-slider" class="slider-pro bsnojs" style="display:none;">



</div>
</div>
</div>
```